# Decoding WMA with FFMPeg on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ffmpeg, core-audio, libav

I'm using this function to decode audio, but there is no sound:

```
int decodedBytes;
decodedBytes = avcodec_decode_audio4(myData->pCodecCtx, myData->myFrame, &data_size, &myData->pkt);
```

The data is successfully downloaded, but I don't know where to go from here, since there is no sound at all.

Comment: By "there is no sound" do you mean you don't hear any sound or you don't get any sound sample data? ffmpeg only takes care of decoding, you have to output it to coreaudio, openal etc.

Comment: And please give more context, what is your goal? error messages or codes? more sample code i probably needed to.

Comment: I've sound sample data, all fields of AVCodecContext, AVCodec, AVFrame, AVPacket and AVFormatContext are filled, but I can't seem to output them properly using AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer. Do you need to see more code? Would you like me to send that to you via email? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Post the code to a pastbin and link to it

Comment: Hi Mattias. Could you please send me an email, than I'll send you a Dropbox link with the FFMPeg libraries. I think that's the best way to see the code working. And don't worry, it's a very basic project. Please send an email to neo-winston@hotmail.com Thanks!

Comment: Yeah but more people can help you if you post a link, and that's what stackoverflow is all about.

Comment: Is the output callback called? do you get noise if you insert random sample data? do you run this in a background thread of the main thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `avcodec_decode_audio3` instead it seams to work:

```
decodedBytes = avcodec_decode_audio3(myData->pCodecCtx, samples, &data_size, &myData->pkt);
```

But you should probably use `avcodec_decode_audio4` as `avcodec_decode_audio3` seams to be deprecated. I don't know much about ffmpeg/libav but I would guess that the audio4 uses the buffer system in libav instead of you passing in a buffer.

Maybe this diff will give a hint how to use audio4:

http://git.libav.org/?p=libav.git;a=commitdiff;h=f199f38573c4c02753f03ba8db04481038fa6f2e

Comment: Thanks! I'm taking a look on that.

Comment: Yes, it's working with avcodec_decode_audio3, but I have to figure out how to make it work using avcodec_decode_audio4. Thanks!

Comment: Until now I couldn't make any useful change to use avcodec_decode_audio4. Any idea on how to do that?